# laravel Backbone page load without refresh

Tags: backbone.js, laravel, tabs

I am using laravel and backbone and have many modules in my application like contacts , tasks etc  Here are my route.php

```
Route::get('task', array('uses' => 'TaskController@render'))->before('auth');               Route::get('contact', array('uses' => 'ContactController@render'))->before('auth');
```

and render function in controller looks like
    public function render() {
    return View::make('task');
    } 
and backbone views(view/model/collections) are used to render.
task.blade.php  extends application.blade.php(this file has the navigation)

How can I have these links as tabs so that i can navigate between these without page refresh.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not certain that your question has anything to do with Laravel, but is mainly related to your front-end JavaScript.

If you are looking to handle dynamic SPA routing, I would recommend looking at something like AngularJS or EmberJS which has routing support built-in.

Otherwise, you need for a routing library that will handle this on the front end.